Merging two (or more) selected objects in GeoJSON file within QGIS
I need to merge two selected, but spatially unconnected, polygon objects into one polygon object within QGIS. They both have the same attribute value within the one attribute field. The file is a GeoJSON.
I can see this is possible when using a shapefile (1-make layer editable, 2-select polygons to be merged, 3-select 'Merge Selected Features'). However, this method doesn't seem to work with GeoJSON files.
When I try the same approach with the GeoJSON I get this error:

"Merge failed - Resulting geometry type (multipart) is incompatible
with layer type (singlepart)".


How can I get around this issue whilst still using GeoJSON?

Please, do not forget about "What should I do when someone answers my question?"

Merging the two singlepart geometries results multipart geometry. You can change singlepart geometry type to multipart by exporting your layer.

right click on your GeoJSON layer in the Layers list and select Export/Save features As... from the popup menu
In the opened dialog box specify the format, filename, crs, etc
under the geometry group check Force multi-type and export it
continue the merging process with the exported multipart geometry layer


Thanks for that @Zoltan. Changing the geometry group type allowed me to merge polygon objects. Thanks
